# Proguard is running desping being disabled

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I have a project with multiple modules. 
For BuildType debug I have set

> minifyEnabled false

which must disable the proguard. Still, when I run the app the proguard is running!

Comment: Is it with gradle command line your trying to run the app?  If not (guess your using Android Studio) can we see your build.gradle ?

Comment: I cannot give it in a full disclosure. Any particular parts which would help?

Comment: I don't really know, but are you sure about your BuildType tag. Also it's "buildTypes". You can remove or replace your private stuff with some random comment before posting. Also what is the version of Android Studio you're using?